# Code for getting certain columns values only as output not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table data and a few columns and I am trying to display the values of certain columns only. I wrote this below code but it is not working correctly. giving some error.

```
$daily = mysql_query("SELECT email, first_name, last_name AS dval FROM users");
while( $stat = mysql_fetch_assoc($daily)) 
{
    echo '<br/>' . " {$stat['dval']}";
}
```

Only the first_name of all the entries is being printed. How can I get the email and last name?

Comment: Can you please post the error?

Comment: @CodyBonney I got the error solved just now, but now the problem is using this code only the first_name is being displayed and there are uneven spaces between the names.....cannot get the email and last name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the query with [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query):

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT email, first_name, last_name AS dval FROM `data`");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result);
echo $row['dval'];
```

I changed your variable names to use the common naming convention.

To get more than one row to print, use a `while` loop:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)) {
    echo $row['dval'];
}
```

Note that the mysql_* functions are being deprecated, and you should switch to either [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo).

Why would anything but `$stat['dval']` print? You only said `echo $stat['dval'];`.

Add the things you want to print in the `while` loop:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)) {
    // HERE is where you add the things you want to print
    echo $row['email'];
    echo $row['first_name'];
    echo $row['dval'];
}
```

Comment: yaya i have that included. but the thing is only the first value is being printed i.e just the firstname of first entry....the remaining rows are not being printed

Comment: @user1424394 - Check your question, it's **not** included. How is anybody supposed to know what's wrong if you don't post the code you're using?

Comment: The other two fields are not coming...only first_name is coming. Can't get the email and last name to be displayed

Comment: I'm done guessing what code you're using. Update your question with the actual code.

Comment: Is there a way we could get the result displayed in a table format?